# Is there a way to put grid lines on top of a contour plot?

Tags: matlab, 3d, grid, contour

I am using the contourf function to create a contour plot:

[image]

I would like to get grid lines to appear on top of the plane that shows the contours.

I came across one solution, but it only works in 2D (that is when you view the contour plot in 2D) which involved the following two commands:

```
grid on
set(gca,'layer','top');
```

However, the grid lines do not appear when viewing the axes in 3D. Is there any way to do this simply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish that using `line` object manipulation that re-writes the grid lines, or a small FEX tool called  [gridxy](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9973-gridxy-v2-2-feb-2008) . 
For example, lets recreate a figure that has the same properties:

```
figure
set(gcf,'Renderer','OpenGL')

%# plot surface and contour
Z = peaks;
surf(Z), hold on
[~,h] = contourf(Z);       %# get handle to contourgroup object

%# change the ZData property of the inner patches
hh = get(h,'Children');    %# get handles to patch objects
for i=1:numel(hh)
    zdata = ones(size( get(hh(i),'XData') ));
    set(hh(i), 'ZData',-10*zdata)
end
```

And add the extra grid lines:

```
v = get(gca);
hg=gridxy(get(gca,'XTick'),get(gca,'YTick'), 'Color',[1,1,1]*0.25,'Linestyle',':');
set(hg,'Zdata',repmat(v.ZLim(1)+eps,[1 numel(get(hg,'Ydata'))]));
```

[image]

---

**However**, is there a reason not to use `surfc` ? For example:

```
Z = peaks(20);
surfc(Z);
view(-45, 20);
```

[image]

Comment: Hey natan, your example is excellent and works fine. However, when I use the same code that you have provided but with a different dataset, the contour plot comes out malformed (as you rotate the plot, the contours and colors change, and the grid lines appear/disappear). All, I have done is use a different matrix for Z: http://pastebin.com/2eXaWriC (your code + data for Z). I tried taking the absolute value to see if negative numbers were the cause, and also set Z = Z(1:5,1:5) to see if making the matrix square would help, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: in my example, the lower `ZLim` value is the same as the position in Z of the contour (that is: `-10*zdata`). This is not always the case, you may generalize and force `ZLim` lower value to be exactly the same as the `-10*zdata` or whereever you want that contour to be. I just demonstrated an example of this. As for the visibility of the lines, if you zoom in you should see them ok, this is probably a matlab rendering issue. Try a different renderer (zbuffer or OpenGL) and see if it helps.